# How do I start auto increment from a specific point?

Tags: sql, mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `batchinfo` (
  `rowid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `datapath` mediumtext,
  `analysistime` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reporttime` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastcalib` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `analystname` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reportname` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `batchstate` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `instrument` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`rowid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `rowid_UNIQUE` (`rowid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15034 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I want to start the auto incremenet from 20000.

How do I do that? Can I edit the table some how to start incrementing from 20000?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE batchinfo AUTO_INCREMENT = 20000;
```

See also [Autoincrement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Comment: After Mysql restart, the auto_increment value changes :(

Answer (score 16):

See the last line of your query:

```
AUTO_INCREMENT=15034
```

Change it to:

```
AUTO_INCREMENT=20000
```

Easy as that! :)

```
CREATE TABLE `batchinfo` (
  `rowid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `datapath` mediumtext,
  `analysistime` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reporttime` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastcalib` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `analystname` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reportname` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `batchstate` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `instrument` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`rowid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `rowid_UNIQUE` (`rowid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20000 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO batchinfo (datapath) values('test');
SELECT * FROM batchinfo;
```

Answer (score 10):

I don't know how to do it from the `CREATE` statement, but after that you can do this:

```
ALTER TABLE `batchinfo` AUTO_INCREMENT = 20000;
```