# Can I assume that the auto increment field will never be equal to 0?

Tags: php, database

if i have code like that:

```
//Returns id or null
$id = $my_db_abstraction_object->getRecord($crits);
if($id)
  do_something();
```

can i assume that id of my record isn't 0? Or - in other worlds - can I assume that every DB by default starts AutoIncrement from 1?

Comment: Every DB by default doesn't have an auto increment feature. You'll need to be specific about which databases you're targeting.

Comment: Not only that, but not every table is going to use an integer as an index or primary key.

Comment: You cold do a strict check for null there. `if($id === null)` or `if(is_null($id))`. At least that would work if your db abstraction returned null as suggested by your comment.

Comment: Already answered here,I think
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470246/mysql-how-do-i-start-auto-increment-from-a-specific-point

Answer (score -1):

If you set the field to be auto incremented it will start at 1 unless you specify otherwise.

Comment: Can you guarantee this to be true in every database that has been created, currently exists, or will be created? The answer is *no*.

Comment: if YOU create the DB and set the field to auto increment...yes you can guarantee it will be 1 unless YOU manually set it otherwise. Notice my use of the word YOU.

Comment: Perhaps you don't understand the purpose of the OPs code. He is creating an abstract interface that would be used with any data access layer. Some database systems don't even have the option of auto-incrementing keys. Period.

Comment: Point taken but OP asked "can I assume that every DB by default starts AutoIncrement from 1?" So I would assume the OP is asking about DB systems that have the AI option.

Comment: Even then, you added a caveat by saying that he can assume that so long as he has control to set it to start from 1. He's not assuming anything in that case.

Comment: OP stated "my record" but I understand your pov.