# Unique id for each row in mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, indexing, mysqli

Here is the code that I've used

**html**:

```
<form action = 'insert.php' method='POST'>
<input type = "text" name = "name">
<input type = "submit" name = "submit">
</form>
```

**php**:

```
<?php
$servername='localhost';
$username='noob';
$password='password';
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);
    if (!$conn) 
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
$a=$_POST['name'];
mysqli_query("INSERT INTO table1 (name) VALUES ('$a')");
?>
```

Right now, the code above inserts a name into a table called table 1. My question now is, say I input many names into the table, but I want each name to have a unique 6 character/digit id. How would I change this code? For example, after 3 inserts, the table should look like this:

```
[table 1]
name               unique_id
NAME1              994323
NAME2              832344
NAME3              332123
```

Each value of `unique_id` must be unique. Is there any efficient way to do this?

Comment: please learn to format your question properly

Comment: Create a unique key in mysql for this column

Comment: If you're ok with a sequential `unique_id`, you can make it an auto increment column and set the initial value to `100000`, the first number with 6 digits. Refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470246/mysql-how-do-i-start-auto-increment-from-a-specific-point) on how to do that. Despite the way you choose to create your unique id, your table will be limited to 899999 records. Maybe that can be a concern.

Comment: The code posted does not show any attempt to achieve the desired result. It is not clear if you are having a specific problem with what you have tried or if you are asking about possible strategies to approach this. Remember that Stack Overflow is about [good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as good answers. and is not a code-writing service. Please do not ask us to write your code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the **random code generation** you can use [RAND()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) as 
To obtain a random integer N in the range a <= N < b, just use the expression FLOOR(a + RAND() * (b – a)) as described in mysql docs

Your query is vulnerable to SQL Injection, fix it with [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) !

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT FLOOR(100000 + RAND() * 990000) AS random_num
    FROM table1 
    WHERE random_num NOT IN (SELECT table1.code FROM table1)
    LIMIT 1");
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$code = $row[0];

mysqli_query("INSERT INTO table1 (name, code) VALUES ('$name', '$code')");
```

This is the working query for random digit generation: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2acd3/1

EDIT:

Personally I prefer [PDO](http://php.net/manual/it/book.pdo.php) instead of mysqli functions, anyway,

someone asked my **why** I suggest the PDO instead of MySQLi function. This is the way that I suggested, You can use whatever you want

- Database Support

  - PDO has 12 different drivers
  - MySQLi has only Mysql driver
- API

  - PDO: only OOP (avoiding bad practice)
  - MySQLi OOP or Procedural
- Named parameters

  - PDO: yes
  - MySQLi no
- Prepared statements (client side)

  - PDO: yes
  - MySQLi: no

Comment: Is there any direct documentation you can provide on why you __suggest__ PDO over MySQLi other than your own preferred method?

Comment: Using this solution, it's possible to have duplicate values or a constraint error if the column has a unique key. I think you need to check if the value doesn't exist in the table before insert.

Comment: PDO just for more best practice approach http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use--net-24059

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use timestamp which is unique but its not 6 digit rather its more than that .For this to work you have to use varchar as column data type and use php function `time()`. This will generate unique digit.For this increase your column length to apprx 15.

Comment: As you said, it isn't a 6 digit value.

Comment: Yes its not but unique .indeed .. Just need to increase your column length. This is example 1443298042