# Auto Generate code (ID) from specific number in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

I am on the beginner level in PHP using SQL. I have created a table in DB and i am try that my code(id) will start from 100 and so on. That will be auto generated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3470267/4248328   . something similar you can do in sql-server  also i hope

Comment: AUTO_INCREMENT=100

Answer (score 1):

Please Use this

```
   ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT=100;
```