# Renew Auto Increment in MySql

Tags: mysql

Suppose i have an auto incremented column named 'ID' and it is going on like 1,2,3,4 but after 4 i want it to start from 1 again.
So it will be like 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2...and so on.
So how to reinitialize the auto increment to 0?
I have tried with this also but no solution .

```
ALTER TABLE 'TABLENAME' AUTO_INCREMENT=0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set initial value and auto increment in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485668/how-to-set-initial-value-and-auto-increment-in-mysql)

Comment: Why do you want to use duplicate values for an `ID` column?

Comment: @Progman That's not correct. He wants it to go from 0 to 4, and then back to 0 again, reusing values for his ID.

Comment: Because i need to separate those slots which will be needed for my work

Comment: No @Progman, that link is not my solution

Comment: My recommendations: Use a custom trigger on insert. SELECT a value from another table (Something like auto_increment), increment that, and if it's over 4, set it to 0. Update the updated increment index, and then update your column on insert.

Comment: Actually @FrankerZ that 4 is not constant for my work actually it will happen upon clicking on a button

Comment: It's something that you're going to have to do manually regardless, either through a trigger or when you insert the object.

Comment: In practice, nobody ever needs to store data like this. You can just take the modulus of a regular ai

Comment: Echoing @Strawberry. Tell us what you are actually after, because doing what you want to do is definitely not the solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql: how do i start auto increment from a specific point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470246/mysql-how-do-i-start-auto-increment-from-a-specific-point)

Answer (score 1):

Don't confuse data storage with data retrieval and display

```
create table my_table (id serial primary key);

insert into my_table values 
(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9);

select id, mod(id-1,3) x from my_table;
id x
 1 0
 2 1
 3 2
 4 0
 5 1
 6 2
 7 0
 8 1
 9 2
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7f460/3

Note also that the construction of 'x' could be handled just as easily (and perhaps more effectively) in application code